# get last command line entry from bash in a tcsh shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, tcsh

Is there a command in tcsh to get the last command that was entered into the shell?

The problem is that the last command will be "tcsh" from a bash shell as I switch my shell from bash to tcsh. Would I need some sort of inter-shell communication to do this? I could try to read the last line in my bash history, that would work ... I think ... maybe sometimes?

Here is the problem:

I would like to make my default shell bash. It is currently tcsh. I do not have admin privileges but I can modify my rc files. Right now I have a work around by placing "bash" or "exec bash" from my .tcshrc file. However this obviously prevents me from ever using tcsh because if I try it runs the rc file and switches back to bash.

Here is my idea:

Write an if statement into my .cshrc file to skip the bash command if the last command was "tcsh".

It should look something like this:

```
if ( STATEMENT HERE ) then
    bash 
endif
```

Where as "STATEMENT HERE" should be false when the last command entered into the shell was "tcsh".

Comment: You should still be able to run `chsh` to change your default shell, even without root privileges.

Comment: Use an environment variable that you set just prior to starting `bash` to indicate whether you've already auto-started `bash`.

Comment: Running chsh was another suggestion I found online when I try it says I must use "ypchsh" ... so I try that and enter my password and it says "the login shell has been changed". Then I close the terminal window and open another and sadly it still opens as tcsh. Maybe I need some flags or options? All the options I tied from other online suggestions caused errors. I was just reading more about this and maybe it worked and I have to log out and back in... I'll try that.

Comment: I could make an environment variable. I like that. It would get me to a better spot. I would however like to eventually be able to do it without setting an environment variable.

Comment: Have you tried asking the admins to change your login shell?

Comment: haha, I was just thinking about that. I'd feel small if I should have gone to the admins instead of stackoverflow :). I'll give that one a try also.

Answer (score 0):

If you really cannot change your login shell, try something like:

```
exec bash -l
```

in ~/.login instead of .cshrc or .tcshrc, so that your tcsh login shell is immediately replaced with a bash login shell.

Working around ~/.bash_history or ~/.history content seems awkward if the main goal is to get your login sessions to start out in bash.

Comment: Thanks. This problem is frustrating me. For the rest of the day I'm leaving it as is. I'll try your work around tomorrow. It would make sense that I should be able to use something as easy as ypchsh but its not happening for me. Mayble I blew threw some typos and did not see them. After I try your idea I'll go back and try the others again.